# mfa authentication app options on azure ad b2c

Tags: azure-active-directory

How come the Azure AD B2C MFA options are limited to email and sms/voice? Other providers have auth apps that the user can install on their alternate devices. Microsoft also has an auth app. Why is using that not an option?

[image]

Comment: It's on the roadmap. You can vote this [User Voice post](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/19225414-add-support-for-the-microsoft-authenticator-app-in#{toggle_previous_statuses}).

Comment: If you accept authentication app options on B2C custom policy, see https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/custom-mfa-totp.

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you** for your **feedback!**. Our product team is working on this feature and currently We can't commit GA to this request at this point in time.

Here you have a use case related to what you need

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/custom-mfa-totp and for sign-in Please refer https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-with-authenticator

Comment: Not sure why you can't commit to this asap as your director of Identity Services says Sms/voice is insecure and we should move away from it asap: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/it-s-time-to-hang-up-on-phone-transports-for-authentication/ba-p/1751752